# Ask the user to input two strings and check whether one string is a substring of another in prolog

Tags: string, prolog, substring, swi-prolog

I'm new to prolog. I just wrote some code. Can you please help me out with this question. Thank you.

My Code:

```
write('Enter the first string:'), nl, 
write('Enter the second string:'), nl.
```

How to proceed from here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`run` rule will drive the experiment.. `.pl` file

```
substring(X,S) :-
    string_to_list(X, XL),
    string_to_list(S, SL),
    append(_,T,SL) ,
    append(XL,_,T) ,
    X \= [], !.
    
% example
% ?- substring("aa", "abaa").
%   true.
% ?- substring("aa", "ababa").
%   false.

run :- write('Enter the first string: '), read(Str1), nl, write('Enter the second string: '), read(Str2), nl,
        (substring(Str1, Str2) -> format('~w is contained in ~w', [Str1, Str2]); format('~w is not in ~w', [Str1, Str2])).
        
% example
% ?- run.
```

Usage..

[image]

Comment: Such a use of append will be slow (due to lots of backtracking). Better to use e.g. https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sub_string/5